# Delete files in a folder that are not found in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a code that loops through files and folders' names found in an Excel Spreadsheet, finds them in a folder and deletes them.

The problem is that there are some files and folders that don't appear on the spreadsheet, but still need to be deleted.
My goal is to have more free space.

Someone suggested i copied the folder list into another column, match the file names and then delete the ones that don't match.

I'd prefer automation, though.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
Sub DeleteSpecificFilesAndFolders()

'This module deletes Extracted Files folders, Flat Files folders and Final Flat Files (.txt format)

Const path = "C:\Users\N\Desktop\Kill_function_test\Test folder for deleting\"

Dim r As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim folderpath As String
Dim folderpath_1 As String

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject



Set r2 = Cells(2, 1)

Do Until r2 = ""


folderpath = path & r2 & "\" & "Extracted Files"


'Checks if the folder exists and then deletes it.
If fso.FolderExists(folderpath) Then

    fso.DeleteFolder (folderpath)

End If


'Checks if the folder exists and then deletes it
folderpath_1 = path & r2 & "\" & "Flat Files"

If fso.FolderExists(folderpath_1) Then

    fso.DeleteFolder (folderpath_1)

End If

Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)

DoEvents
Loop

'Loops through and deletes the "INACTIVE" Final Flat Files (.txt)
Set r = Cells(1, 5)

Do Until r = ""
    If UCase(r.Value) = "INACTIVE" Then
        'Checks if the extracted flat file exists.
        If Dir(path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & "Final Flat Files" & "\" & r.Offset(0, 1) & ".txt") <> "" Then
            Kill path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & "Final Flat Files" & "\" & r.Offset(0, 1) & ".txt"
        End If
    End If
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: *"The problem is that there are some files and folders that don't appear on the spreadsheet, but still need to be deleted."* And what is particular to those file names? How do you know which you want to delete? Can you give an example?

Comment: So your code works but you want to find another way?

Comment: The code just deletes the files and folders that appear on the spreadsheet.

Comment: The first part of the code deletes unnecessary folders called "Extracted Flat files" and "Flat Files" that match the names found on the spreadsheet. If you click on the actual folder, you would see some folders that are still there, because they didn't appear on the spreadsheet.  The 2nd part of the code deletes specific txt files and doesn't need any tweeking.

Comment: {Const path = "C:\Users\NikolouzosD\Desktop\Kill_function_test\Test folder for deleting\"
Set r2 = Cells(2, 1)

Do Until r2 = ""
folderpath = path & r2 & "\" & "Extracted Files"}
To be more specific:
r2 gets the folder name for each row and pastes it into the path above. Then the code finds this folder and deletes it.

Comment: @Dimitri So what you want is to delete the folders that exists in C:\Users\NikolouzosD\Desktop\Kill_function_test\Test folder for deleting... But are not written in the excel?

Comment: @KhalidSaifaldeen I want to delete the folders tha don't exist in the Excel Spreadsheet. Yes

Comment: @Dimitri So if you want to delete what exists in the excel sheet and delete what does not exists. You want to delete everything?

Comment: @KhalidSaifaldeen exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. I used the `Dir()` command/function. This allows you to obtain all the folder/files that exists in a path.

```
Sub DeleteSpecificFilesAndFolders()

'This module deletes Extracted Files folders, Flat Files folders and Final Flat Files (.txt format)

Const path = "C:\Users\N\Desktop\Kill_function_test\Test folder for deleting\"

Dim r As Range
Dim folderpath As String
Dim folderpath_1 As String
Dim FolderName As String 

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

FolderName=Dir(Path & "*", vbDirectory)

While FolderName <> ""

if Not FolderName like "*.*" then  'This is because when using Dir(,vbdirectory) you can get . and .. or if files exist

  folderpath = path & FolderName & "\" & "Extracted Files"


  'Checks if the folder exists and then deletes it.
  If fso.FolderExists(folderpath) Then

      fso.DeleteFolder (folderpath)

  End If


  'Checks if the folder exists and then deletes it
  folderpath_1 = path & FolderName & "\" & "Flat Files"

  If fso.FolderExists(folderpath_1) Then

      fso.DeleteFolder (folderpath_1)

  End If

end if

FolderName=Dir() 'This will set FolderName to the next folder 

DoEvents
wend

'Loops through and deletes the "INACTIVE" Final Flat Files (.txt)
Set r = Cells(1, 5)

Do Until r = ""
    If UCase(r.Value) = "INACTIVE" Then
        'Checks if the extracted flat file exists.
        If Dir(path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & "Final Flat Files" & "\" & r.Offset(0, 1) & ".txt") <> "" Then
            Kill path & r.Offset(0, -4) & "\" & "Final Flat Files" & "\" & r.Offset(0, 1) & ".txt"
        End If
    End If
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: brilliant! It works like a charm.  Thank you very much for your help. :)